# Bottle Cork creates a user, but it doesn't save it to the database

Tags: python, sqlite, bottle

I'm using Bottle Cork for autentification with an SQLite backend and am trying to create a user:

```
@bottle.post('/ajax/users/create/')
def create_user():
    response.content_type = 'application/json'
    password = bottle.request.forms.get('password')
    username = bottle.request.forms.get('username')
    role = bottle.request.forms.get('role')
    ret = create_user_by_admin(username, password, role)
    response.content_type = 'application/json'
    return dumps({"status": ret.get('ok')})

def create_user_by_admin(username, password, role):
    try:
        auth.create_user(username, role, password)
        return dict(ok=True, msg='')
    except Exception, e:
        return dict(ok=False, msg=e.message)
```

Bottle app logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jul/2014 13:56:38] "POST /ajax/users/create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16
```

jQuery post response: {"status": true}

If I'm creating a user the first time, the response is True (user successfully created), but there are no new user in the database. The next response will return False and an error message:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jul/2014 13:56:38] "POST /ajax/users/create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16
/home/art/projects/leggera/app/views.py:33: DeprecationWarning: BaseException.message        has been deprecated as of Python 2.6
return dict(ok=False, msg=e.message)
```

That means, that a user was created, but... There are still no new user in the database (I'm using SQLiteMan for viewing the content of the database)!
The database is not locked, `chmod +rwx`... How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Looking at the [backend source code](https://github.com/FedericoCeratto/bottle-cork/blob/master/cork/sqlite_backend.py) I'd say the changes are never committed. There is no auto-commit configuration nor explicit commit anywhere. That's a surprising bug in a package already over a year old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backend implementation doesn't ever commit the transaction.

There are two issues in the Cork issue tracker that show how people are working around this:

- [Issue 66](https://github.com/FedericoCeratto/bottle-cork/pull/66) is a pull request to update the examples to add `backend.connection.commit()` calls:

  ```
  auth.create_user(username, role, password)
  auth._store.connection.commit()
  ```
- [Issue 63](https://github.com/FedericoCeratto/bottle-cork/issues/63) is about threading issues with the SQLite backend; but the included code uses a *subclass* of the backend to set the isolation level to force autocommitting.

Note that issue 63 shows that the backend is wholly unsuitable for multi-threaded environments; I'd use the SQLAlchemy backend instead as it handles SQLite and threads properly.

A quick cursory glance at that backend also makes it look like it doesn't handle committing either though.

Comment: Yes, auth._store.connection.commit() works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think that solution its redefinition of functions(save_users, save_roles, save_pending_registrations) in sqlite_backend.py:

`def save_users(self):
    self.connection.commit()
def save_roles(self):
    self.connection.commit()
def save_pending_registrations(self):
    self.connection.commit()`